# Accessibility Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, accessibility

I need to optimize the existing route in my city for my undergrad thesis. So the idea I had is to use a tool to analyze the current existing route's accessibility and comparing it to the accessibility of the new route I'm about to design by trial and error (Designing multiple new routes and finding the one with the biggest accessibility differences). But I'm completely blind for this tool.

Is there any existing tool I can use? Or a plugin? Or do I need to create my own algorithm in the create new script menu?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what do **you** mean by accessability?

Comment: How easy it is to reach it by walking. So to say how many people that live in the area can easily access that route within 200 m walking distance. The closest i've found to the goal i'm trying to get is the service area tool from network analysis, but i'm going for the whole route instead of points. And it'd be nice if it were able to give me numbers / percentage but im assuming it isnt possible.